# CyanogenMod no keyboard

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola, motorola-xoom

I have cyanogen mod on my Motorola Xoom. I did a reset and now I cannot access my keyboard. It's says 'unfortunately keyboard has stopped working.' I'm not connected to the internet. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Sideload a keyboard APK from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to internet than you can't do anything, however if you have internet on your PC and USB cable or your friend have internet on their phone you can download .apk file of let's say GBoard from apkmirror.com and transfer it to your phone via USB/Bluetooth and than install (first enable unknown sources in settings>security). And set new keyboard as default in settings> language and keyboard. If you new keyboard crashes as old one let me know, on CM for my old phone I had to delte some lib file to make keyboards work.